# findOne() in Meteor iron router returns undefined

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, iron-router, subscriptions

Mi browser throws the next error to console

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined  router.js:16
```

when I try to run this code:

```
///////////////////////////////////
// FILE: /router.js
///////////////////////////////////

Router.configure({
    layoutTemplate : "main"
});

Router.route('main',{
    path : '/',
    template : 'main',
    waitOn: function() {
        return [
            Meteor.subscribe('userdata'),
            Meteor.subscribe('portrait')
        ];
    },
    data: function() {
        return {
            name: UserData.findOne().name,
            portrait: Portraits.findOne()
        };
    }
});

////////////////////////////////////////
// FILE: /client/main.html
////////////////////////////////////////

<template name="main">
    <header>
        My School
        <br>
        {{#if currentUser}}
            {{name}}
            <img src="{{portrait.url}}">
            <a href="{{pathFor 'login'}}" id="logout">Logout</a>
        {{/if}}
    </header>
    <div>
        {{> yield}}
    </div>
</template>

////////////////////////////////////////////
// FILE: /server/publications.js
////////////////////////////////////////////

Meteor.publish("userdata",function() {
    return UserData.find({user : this.userId});
});

Meteor.publish("portrait",function() {
    var portraitId = UserData.findOne({user : this.userId}).portrait;
    return Portraits.find({_id : portraitId});
});

///////////////////////////////////////////
// FILE: /lib/portraits.js
///////////////////////////////////////////
var portraitsStore = new FS.Store.FileSystem("portraits",{path : '~/Applications/meteor/school/server/uploads'});

Portraits = new FS.Collection("portraits",{
    stores : [portraitsStore]
});

///////////////////////////////////////////
// FILE: /lib/userdata.js
///////////////////////////////////////////

UserData = new Mongo.Collection('userdata');
```

There isn't any problem when I use subscriptions to retrieve data in Template.principal.helpers. The problem is with iron router.

I'm using ubuntu 14.04 whit chrome, thank you

Comment: are there any records created by the current user in the `usuarios` `Collection`?

Comment: yes, I check it in mongo console

Comment: You have posted code that is not translated to English. Stack Overflow is an international community, translating your variable and function names and your comments to English will greatly improve the clarity of your question for international readers and will increase the likelihood of your question being answered.

Comment: ok, I edited the post, now in english. Sorry about my english